# Display all changed names with tibble/as_tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, display

See the example below:

```
 > mutations <- as_tibble(mutations, .name_repair = "universal")
    7 New names:
    6 * `primary coverage` -> primary.coverage
    5 * `meta coverage` -> meta.coverage
    4 * `blood coverage` -> blood.coverage
    3 * `primary RNA` -> primary.RNA
    2 * `primary RNA coverage` -> primary.RNA.coverage
    1 * … and 6 more problems
```

How can you display the remaining "6 problems"?

Comment: you just want something to check? try this, new <- colnames(as_tibble(mutations, .name_repair = "universal")) ; paste(colnames(mutations),new,sep="->")[colnames(mutations) != new]

Comment: @StupidWolf well that's a solution

Comment: Have you tried `problems(mutations)`?